# JHipster - Change the basePath for FrontEnd

Tags: angular, webpack, jhipster

What I want to achieve is a basic **JHipster** Project with the FrontEnd (in my case Angular) that is served by not the default `/` but from the `/something-else`.
This because I want to place some other content inside the `/`.

I've seen this similar question: [How to set base url for Angular application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55705637/how-to-set-base-url-for-angular-application) but it didn't help me.

I would like to set that behavior for all the profiles: dev/prod/etc.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How set up a Context Path on a Jhipster (spring boot + angular) application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59843787/how-set-up-a-context-path-on-a-jhipster-spring-boot-angular-application)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to use the Apache/Nginx to do this kind of configuration without changing jhipster context but you can do it like this:

First you need to add `context-path` on you `application.yml`:

```
server.servlet.context-path: /something-else/
```

Then you need to update the `webpack.prod.js` or `webpack.common.js` with the proper base attribute value. Considering jhipster as the context path, the base attribute value should looks like:

```
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    ...
    base: '/something-else/'
})
```

See more information [here](https://www.jhipster.tech/production/)